# How can I get the most specific value from a data stream?

Tags: python

I tried to program a server (UDP Socket) to allow a data exchange between my PC and a sensor in testing machine. I receive from a sensor continually a data like this:

```
0.00;0.966458;4.75;0.000160

0.00;0.976958;4.75;0.000160

S reached (1)

0.00;0.986958;4.75;0.000160

0.00;1.001051;-2.25;0.000160
```

Each second I receive one or more lines. It depends on frequency, which I setup. All data, which I send to machine (commands) or receive (measured data from sensor) are "strings".

**My goal:**
as soon I receive from a sensor: "S reached (1)", I want to save the next received line "0.00;0.986958;4.75;0.000160" as a variable. In my case the second value in this line shall be saved as a variable, "0.00;**0.986958**;4.75;0.000160".

As a first step I try to do something easier. When I receive "S reached (1)" the server has to do something.

```
while True:
    data, address = socket.recvfrom(1024)
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    print(data)

    if data == "S reached (1)":
        print("Hello")
```

Unfortunately I don't get "Hello".

Comment: Have you tried trimming whitespace from the received string? e.g. `data = data.decode("utf-8").strip()`

Comment: As per [`socket` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom), `recvfrom` reads *at most* `bufsize` bytes, so you may have been reading more data at once than just a single line.

Comment: @Luke Smith, As for trimming whitespace, I didn't try this yet.

Comment: May you need to add `/n` at the end of the string?

Comment: @asmallorange, a sensor in a machine sent me always a one line at each time step.

Comment: @LukeSmith, Many thanks. `data = data.decode("utf-8").strip()` works.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably some trailing whitespace. Stripping it off should solve the problem:

```
data = data.decode("utf-8").strip()
```